# Sorting card hands

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

For start, I'm sorry for asking this question because I know it probably is duplicated, triplicated...or so. But I've read a few answers and still can't get my code to work as I need it to.

I have an array players[] with four arrays inside, players[0][0 to 12], players[1][0 to 12], players[2][0 to 12] and players[3][0 to 12].

Each position has an image element, previously shuffled.

What I want to do is sort each hand by id.

I tried this:

```
function sortHands(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    players[i].sort(function(a, b){return (a.id - b.id);});
  }
}
```

How can I get this to work, so in the end I have the same array of arrays but with the elements sorted?

In simple JavaScript...

Anyone?

Comment: Why are you using the second for loop? Since you are not using the variable "j" anywhere? There is no need for that loop.

Comment: @wazaaaap You're right...already edited.

Comment: Should be working now: http://jsfiddle.net/5akhbsw7/

Comment: @blex still not working...maybe it is working but it doesn't show. The sorted hands stay in the same array or are they returned somewere else? I really am a begginer :/

Comment: `someArray.sort()` alters the original Array, it does not create a new one, as you can see in the JS Fiddle (I'm logging the same array twice, but the order is different). If you still can't make it work with your code, the problem might come from somewhere else.

Comment: @blex can you please tell me how can I see it working in JSFiddle? When I click run, the result keeps empty.

Comment: Open your JS console (hit F12). That's where the result is.

Comment: @blex Sorry, just one more thing: Is it normal that `console.log( 'before: ', JSON.stringify(players) );` shows `[[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]]`? And after shows the same :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81815/discussion-between-blex-and-razoes).